# Play Framework 1: tag to include javascript file only once

Tags: java, playframework

In `Play Framework 1`, is there a tag which includes javascript file only once in the generated page?

Example:

I want following code:

```
#{press.script 'my.script.js'}
#{press.script 'my.script.js'}
```

to inject `my.script.js` declaration into resulting page only once, so that Play generates the following:

```
<script src="/path/to/my.script.js"></script>
```

Please note that `press` module should be of `version >= 1.0.22`.

So far, anything but not what's needed was found:

- `#{press.script 'my.script.js'}` simply throws exception when specified twice with same js file
- version `1.0.11` of `press` module added `ignoreDuplicates` tag property which, as per documentation, should do what's needed, but in next version it was **mysteriously removed** ...
- version `1.0.12` of `press` module added possibility to add `press.allowDuplicates` to configuration, but in next version it was again **mysteriously removed** ...
- `#{press.single-script 'my.script.js'}` simply compresses js file and adds `<script>` twice to generated file

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is. I have solved a similar problem like this.

Let's say I have one template, `main.html`. All other templates extend this one. `Main.html` includes `scripts.html`. Based on the current URL, the Controller renders `form.html` which extends `main.html`. In `form.html` I have a widget which needs `my.script.js`. To make sure it's only included on this page (which needs the script) I've set the following variable:

```
#{set useMyScript: true /}
```

In `scripts.html`, I will check this variable and render this script only if needed:

```
#{if useMyScript}
    #{press.script 'my.script.js'}
#{/if}
```

So, this is not exactly your case, but I am pretty sure you can set useMyScript to true multiple times with this solution and include the Javascript only once.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I've also came to the same conclusion after spending an hour of googling. Thanks for the reply! :)